# Subsection fontsize

Tags: fontsize

I'm doing a project divided in sections and subsections. In the first subsection, the size of the text becomes automatically smaller, but in the second one it doesn't and I don't understand why.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\cwave}[2]{
    \textcolor{#1}{\uwave{\textcolor{black}{#2}}}
}
\newcommand{\minr}[1]{\textcolor{PineGreen}{\bm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\per}[1]{\stackrel{\textcolor{red}{\textit{\textbf{#1}}}}{=}}


\usepackage{comment}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\tikzstyle{branch}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt]

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Individuazione della funzione Booleana}
    \subsection{Minterm}
    Evidenziamo i termini minimi della funzione $f(x, y, z, w)$ appena identificata. \\
    
    \begin{center}
        \scalebox{1.30}{%
            \begin{tabular}{c | c || c c c c || c}
                & & $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $w$ & $f(x, y, z, w)$ \\
                \hline
                \color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_0$ & $\color{PineGreen}\overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1} \\
                $m_1$ & $\overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
                \color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_2$ & $\color{PineGreen}\overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:z\:\overline{w}$ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1} \\
                $m_3$ & $\overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:z\:w$ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
                $m_4$ & $\overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                \color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_5$ & $\color{PineGreen}\overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:w$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1} \\
                \color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_6$ & $\color{PineGreen}\overline{x}\:y\:z\:\overline{w}$ & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1} \\
                $m_7$ & $\overline{x}\:y\:z\:w$ & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
                $m_8$ & $x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}$ & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                \color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_9$ & $\color{PineGreen}x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w$ & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1} \\
                $m_{10}$ & $x\:\overline{y}\:z\:\overline{w}$ & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
                \color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_{11}$ & $\color{PineGreen}x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w$ & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1} \\
                \color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_{12}$ & $\color{PineGreen}x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}$ & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1} \\
                \color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_{13}$ & $\color{PineGreen}x\:y\:\overline{z}\:w$ & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1} \\
                $m_{14}$ & $x\:y\:z\:\overline{w}$ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
                $m_{15}$ & $x\:y\:z\:w$ & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
                
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{center}
    
    \hspace*{-0.64cm} Per ottenere la forma canonica della funzione prendo le quaterne in cui \\ la funzione vale 1. \\ \\
    La funzione può essere quindi espressa come somma di prodotti ed è pari a: \\
    
    
    \hspace*{-2.70cm} \scalebox{1.2}{%
        $\bm{f(x, y, z, w)}= \overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w} + \overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:z\:\overline{w} + \overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:w + \overline{x}\:y\:z\:\overline{w} + x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w + x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w} + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:w$
    }
    
    \newpage
    
    
    \hspace*{-0.64cm} Per ottenere la forma canonica della funzione prendo le quaterne in cui \\ la funzione vale 0. \\ \\
    La funzione può essere quindi espressa come prodotti di somme ed è pari a: 
    
    
    \large\vspace*{-0.50cm}\begin{align*}
        \hspace*{-1.50cm}\bm{f(x, y, z, w)} &= (x+y+z+\overline{w}) \cdot (x+y+\overline{z}+\overline{w}) \cdot (x+\overline{y}+z+w) \cdot (x+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+\overline{w}) \cdot \\
        &\hspace*{0.58cm}(\overline{x}+y+z+w) \cdot (\overline{x}+y+\overline{z}+w) \cdot (\overline{x}+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+w) \cdot (\overline{x}+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+\overline{w})
    \end{align*}
    
    \newpage
    \section{Semplificazione}
    \subsection{Semplificazione algebrica minterm}Adesso effettuo la semplificazione della forma canonica della funzione espressa dai minterm.
    La \cwave{PineGreen}{sottolineatura} evidenzia i termini ai quali verrà applicato un teorema o un assioma, che verrà indicato alla fine della riga.
    Il risultato viene evidenziato in \textcolor{PineGreen}{\textbf{verde}}.\\
    
    \begin{align*}
        \hspace*{-2.0cm}\bm{f(x, y, z, w)}= & \:\overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w} + \cwave{PineGreen}{\overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:z\:\overline{w}} + \overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:w + \cwave{PineGreen}{\overline{x}\:y\:z\:\overline{w}} + x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w + x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w} + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:w \per{A6} \\
        %
        & =  \overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w} + \minr{\overline{x}\:z\:\overline{w}\cwave{PineGreen}{\textcolor{PineGreen}{(\overline{y}+y)}}} + \overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:w + x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w + x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w} + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:w \per{A7} \\
        %
        & = \overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w} + \cwave{PineGreen}{\overline{x}\:z\:\overline{w}*\minr{1}} + \overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:w + x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w + x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w} + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:w \per{A3} \\
        %
        & = \overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w} + \minr{\overline{x}\:z\:\overline{w}} + \cwave{PineGreen}{\overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:w} + x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w + x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w} + \cwave{PineGreen}{x\:y\:\overline{z}\:w} \per{A6} \\
        %
        & = \overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w} + \overline{x}\:z\:\overline{w} + \minr{y\:\overline{z}\:w\cwave{PineGreen}{\textcolor{PineGreen}{(\overline{x}+x)}}} + x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w + x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w} \per{A7} \\
        %
    \end{align*}
    
    
\end{document}
```

This is the font size that I want

[image]

This is the font size I get

[image]

Comment: Your document does not compile

Comment: You use `\large` before the second section, so text font will be larger. Is that what you mean with your question? If not, please add a screenshot and highlight which font does not have the size you expect it to have.

Comment: Unrelated: you should not need manual formatting instructions like `\hspace` in your normal text. Also don't use \\ for line breaks (outside of tables) and don't scale stuff which contains text. `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, have a look at `\tikzset` instead. With very few exceptions, you should load `hyperref` after the other packages.

Comment: you should start by removing all the `\scalebox` `\large` and `\vspace` commands which should all be avoided in the body of a document. But your error is `\large` which applies to all the text for the rest of the document

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I want that function to be bigger, I tried writing `\large{...}` but it doesn't change. Also could you explain what should I use instead of \\ ? And I need `\hspace` because the text doesn't go where I want, like it's all to the right or to the left

Comment: You still have the unlimited `\large` in the line "`\large\vspace*{-0.50cm}\begin{align*}`".  That is the reason for the size change.  But there are other problems with the input; the answer by @egreg identifies them.

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton, how can I make the function larger withous using `\large`? I've tried `\large{...}` but it doesn't work

Comment: You can `{\large ...}` and that will scope the `\large`, but that doesn't fix all the problems.  @egreg's answer addresses (most of) the other problems.  I'm not trying to be insulting here, but agree with him that most of the problems indicate that you don't know very well how to use LaTeX.

Comment: @barbarabeeton ok thanks, no problem, this is my first LaTex project so I'm trying to get better

Comment: You might benefit from the tutorials at learnlatex,org .

Comment: @barbarabeeton ok thanks

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but you're committing too many beginner's sins.

1. Never scale tables or equations
2. Never use `\\` to manually break lines, unless where it is needed, such as in `align` or similar environments.
3. Don't use guessed spacing instructions.
4. Paragraphs are terminated with a blank line in the input; don't “leave blank lines in the output”: the indentation is sufficient.
5. Avoid “naked” `\large` instructions: it's a declaration that's only bounded by the scope in which it is executed.
6. Long formulas can be split in various ways; don't let them fill the margins.
7. Beware of spurious spaces in the body of definitions.
8. `\tikzstyle` has been deprecated for some years (more than five, I'd say).

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\cwave}[2]{% <-- don't forget
    \textcolor{#1}{\uwave{\textcolor{black}{#2}}}% <-- don't forget
}
\newcommand{\minr}[1]{\textcolor{PineGreen}{\bm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\per}[1]{\stackrel{\textcolor{red}{\textit{\textbf{#1}}}}{=}}


\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black}

\tikzset{
  branch/.style={
    fill,
    shape=circle,
    minimum size=3pt,
    inner sep=0pt,
  },
}


\begin{document}
    
\section{Individuazione della funzione Booleana}

\subsection{Minterm}

Evidenziamo i termini minimi della funzione $f(x, y, z, w)$ appena identificata.
    
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c | c || c c c c || c}
& & $x$ & $y$ & $z$ & $w$ & $f(x, y, z, w)$ \\
\hline
\color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_0$ &
  $\color{PineGreen}\overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}$ &
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1}
\\
$m_1$ &
  $\overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w$ &
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\\
\color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_2$ &
  $\color{PineGreen}\overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:z\:\overline{w}$ &
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1}
\\
$m_3$ &
  $\overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:z\:w$ &
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\\
$m_4$ &
  $\overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}$ &
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\
\color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_5$ &
  $\color{PineGreen}\overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:w$ &
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1}
\\
\color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_6$ &
  $\color{PineGreen}\overline{x}\:y\:z\:\overline{w}$ &
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1}
\\
$m_7$ &
  $\overline{x}\:y\:z\:w$ &
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\\
$m_8$ &
  $x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}$ &
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\
\color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_9$ &
  $\color{PineGreen}x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w$ &
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1}
\\
$m_{10}$ &
  $x\:\overline{y}\:z\:\overline{w}$ &
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\\
\color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_{11}$ &
  $\color{PineGreen}x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w$ &
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1}
\\
\color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_{12}$ &
  $\color{PineGreen}x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}$ &
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1}
\\
\color{PineGreen}\boldmath$m_{13}$ &
  $\color{PineGreen}x\:y\:\overline{z}\:w$ &
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \color{PineGreen}\textbf{1}
\\
$m_{14}$ &
  $x\:y\:z\:\overline{w}$ &
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
$m_{15}$ &
  $x\:y\:z\:w$ &
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
    
Per ottenere la forma canonica della funzione prendo le quaterne in cui la funzione vale~$1$.

La funzione può essere quindi espressa come somma di prodotti ed è pari a:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\bm{f(x, y, z, w)}
 &= \overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}
  + \overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:z\:\overline{w}
  + \overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:w
  + \overline{x}\:y\:z\:\overline{w}
\\
 &\qquad
  + x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w
  + x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w
  + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}
  + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:w
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Per ottenere la forma canonica della funzione prendo le quaterne in cui la funzione vale~$0$.

La funzione può essere quindi espressa come prodotti di somme ed è pari a: 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\bm{f(x, y, z, w)}
  &= (x+y+z+\overline{w})
   \cdot (x+y+\overline{z}+\overline{w})
   \cdot (x+\overline{y}+z+w)
\\
  &\qquad
   \cdot (x+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+\overline{w})
   \cdot (\overline{x}+y+z+w)
   \cdot (\overline{x}+y+\overline{z}+w)
\\
  &\qquad
   \cdot (\overline{x}+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+w)
   \cdot (\overline{x}+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+\overline{w})
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
    
\section{Semplificazione}

\subsection{Semplificazione algebrica minterm}

Adesso effettuo la semplificazione della forma canonica della funzione espressa dai minterm.
La \cwave{PineGreen}{sottolineatura} evidenzia i termini ai quali verrà applicato un 
teorema o un assioma, che verrà indicato alla fine della riga.
Il risultato viene evidenziato in \textcolor{PineGreen}{\textbf{verde}}.
\begin{align*}
\bm{f(x, y, z, w)}
  &= \overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}
   + \cwave{PineGreen}{\overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:z\:\overline{w}}
   + \overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:w
   + \cwave{PineGreen}{\overline{x}\:y\:z\:\overline{w}}
\\
  &\qquad
   + x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w
   + x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w
   + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}
   + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:w
\\
  &\per{A6}
     \overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}
   + \minr{\overline{x}\:z\:\overline{w}
     \cwave{PineGreen}{\textcolor{PineGreen}{(\overline{y}+y)}}}
   + \overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:w
   + x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w
\\
  &\qquad
   + x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w
   + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}
   + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:w 
\\
  &\per{A7}
     \overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}
   + \cwave{PineGreen}{\overline{x}\:z\:\overline{w}*\minr{1}}
   + \overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:w
   + x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w
\\
  &\qquad
   + x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w
   + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}
   + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:w
\\
  &\per{A3}
     \overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}
   + \minr{\overline{x}\:z\:\overline{w}}
   + \cwave{PineGreen}{\overline{x}\:y\:\overline{z}\:w}
   + x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w
\\
  &\qquad
   + x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w
   + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}
   + \cwave{PineGreen}{x\:y\:\overline{z}\:w}
\\
  &\per{A6}
     \overline{x}\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}
   + \overline{x}\:z\:\overline{w}
   + \minr{y\:\overline{z}\:w\cwave{PineGreen}{\textcolor{PineGreen}{(\overline{x}+x)}}}
\\
  &\qquad
   + x\:\overline{y}\:\overline{z}\:w
   + x\:\overline{y}\:z\:w
   + x\:y\:\overline{z}\:\overline{w}
\\
  &\per{A7}
\end{align*}    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't understand. 
1 How can I make table or equation a little bit bigger or smaller without scaling them? 2 Why can't I use \\ to break lines?
3 How can I place text exactly where I want without guessed spaced instruction?
4 What do you mean by saying **Paragraphs are terminated with a blank line in the input; don't “leave blank lines in the output”: the indentation is sufficient.**?
5 How can I make the function larger without \large?
6 What do you mean by saying fill the margin?
7 What do you mean by saying spurious spaces in the body of definitions

Comment: Sorry for the long comment, hope I don't annoy you but I've just started using latex and also other people in other questions I've asked keep saying to not use \scalebox or \hspace but I don't understand how to replace them.

Comment: @pepper You just *don't* need them! LaTeX ain't no word processor! It's perfectly able to break lines where it's best to do it. You don't need to make equations larger: displaying them is more than enough to highlight them. Making them stick into the margins is bad typography and should be avoided. Just because something can be done in Word doesn't mean it's good.

Comment: Ok thanks but I really want that equation to be bigger, I dont' like how the page looks withe the equation in normal size.

Comment: @pepper Take any math book from your shelf and look at how many equations are made bigger. That's showing off, by the way.

Comment: I don't want to show off, I just think that with the equation bigger the page looks better. Also, it's not really an equation, it's the result that I get so I want to make it a little bit bigger than normal text

Comment: @pepper Please, try and look at books.

Comment: @pepper Font size carries meaning. In most documents it is used to mark hierarchical elements like headlines. If you start mixing different font sizes within the text body, you risk that your document will look like a ransom letter. If you really want to emphasis this special equation, maybe placing it in a box would be less painful for your reader.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz aahhahaha, hope my professor doesn't think that my project looks like a ransom letter but I don't think it looks painful to read but maybe I am the weird one. Thanks for the suggestion.